# call a post api method in c# whereas, you have to set proxy server and port

Tags: c#, api, restful-url

i have to call a post method from a server which forces me to using a special proxy server and port.
i have called post methods in c# by below codes but now, i can not find anywhere setting the special proxy.
please help me
thanks a lot

```
public HttpResponseMessage Authenticate(AuthenticateDTO entity)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://restapi.x.com/SuperClient/V1/APIAUTHENTICATE");

                var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("SuperClient/V1/APIAUTHENTICATE", entity).Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.Write("Success");
                }
                else
                    Console.Write("Error");
            }
            return null;
        }
```